# TypeError: ko.observable array is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm having trouble using Knockout with my website. When I attempt to load my page my browser gives me a `TypeError: ko.observablearray is not a function`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, would this mean that my JS file with knockout hasn't loaded or is there an issue with the way I have formatted my code?

This my first time attempting to use knockout, and Javascript in general so bear with me if this is a simple question.

Here is a snipper of my `app.js` file where the error is being thrown:

```
// --- View Model.
function AppViewModel() {

  // Setting This
  var self = this

  // Declaring Observables
  this.locationInput = ko.observable("");

  this.locationList = ko.observablearray([]);
```

Here is how I am loading my scripts:

```
  <script src="./js/knockout.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
```

What am I not getting about this? I'm more familiar with Python and this error would seem to me like I haven't imported a module if I working with python. I wasn't aware that this was necessary with Javascript; Is there a declaration I need to make in order to use Knockout? Thanks again for any help.

Comment: I think perhaps you just need to capitalize Array in observableArray. heh

Comment: u should read  message error clearly !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires a capital A for the `observableArray`

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray();    // Initially an empty array
myObservableArray.push('Some value');            // Adds the value and notifies observers
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html

And also if you have used

```
var self = this;
```

The following declarations can refer to the `self` directly.

```
// Declaring Observables
self.locationInput = ko.observable("");
self.locationList = ko.observablearray([]);
```

This will be useful when you want to use above objects in a function or a computed object. It will help to point to the right reference. For example:

```
self.getLocation = function(data, event){
  return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.locationList(), function(location) {
        return location.toLowerCase() === data.toLowerCase();
    });
};
```

Comment: Wow I knew it was something simple, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!